# Best Wifi Manager

Tags: wireless, software-recommendation, lan

Which is the best **Wireless LAN Manager** for Ubuntu Linux?

> Is [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net) the best one available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Network Manager is the default manager for Ubuntu.  This doesn't mean it's *the best*, but it does mean that it's a very good solution.

Depending upon your needs, Network Manager is most likely going to provide all the functionality that you need, however, I prefer to use [wicd](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Wicd/), as it interferes less with other configurations.

If you have reasons to leave Network Manager, I would suggest wicd.

Asking which program is 'best' is often not the best way to find what you need.  If you have a specific problem with Network Manager ask about that specifically, instead.

Answer (score 4):

I used wicd for a long time, but I think [Network Manager](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/) has matured quite a bit and is quite a decent all round network (including wifi) manager. Especially since it has support for VPN too.